# Showing Monthly Totals from Multiple Columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, aggregate-functions

I am looking to see the number of firstexam patients seen per month for a given date range this year vs last year, and compare that to the total number of patients seen per month for the same date range.

I am able to set up the firstexam patients as follows:

```
select case EXTRACT(month FROM patient_info.firstexam)
    when 1 then '01 - January'
    when 2 then '02 - February'
    when 3 then '03 - March'
    when 4 then '04 - April'
    when 5 then '05 - May'
    when 6 then '06 - June'
    when 7 then '07 - July'
    when 8 then '08 - August'
    when 9 then '09 - September' 
    when 10 then '10 - October'
    when 11 then '11 - November'
    when 12 then '12 - December'
end as month,
sum(case when patient_info.firstexam >= '2013-01-01' AND patient_info.firstexam <= '2013-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) thisyear,
sum(case when patient_info.firstexam >= '2012-01-01' AND patient_info.firstexam <= '2012-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) lastyear

from patient_info WHERE (patient_info.firstexam >= '2013-01-01' AND patient_info.firstexam <= '2013-12-31' OR patient_info.firstexam >= '2012-01-01' AND patient_info.firstexam <= '2012-12-31') 

GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

This gives me three columns: month, thisyear, lastyear.

Please note: I entered numerical month before month name because I could not get the months to appear in chronological order otherwise. Any hints to not show the number before the month would be appreciated.

I would like to add two more columns for total patients - something like:

```
select case EXTRACT(month FROM patient_info.lastexam)
    when 1 then '01 - January'
    when 2 then '02 - February'
    when 3 then '03 - March'
    when 4 then '04 - April'
    when 5 then '05 - May'
    when 6 then '06 - June'
    when 7 then '07 - July'
    when 8 then '08 - August'
    when 9 then '09 - September' 
    when 10 then '10 - October'
    when 11 then '11 - November'
    when 12 then '12 - December'
end as month,
sum(case when patient_info.lastexam >= '2013-01-01' AND patient_info.lastexam <= '2013-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) totalthisyear,
sum(case when patient_info.lastexam >= '2012-01-01' AND patient_info.lastexam <= '2012-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) totallastyear

from patient_info WHERE (patient_info.lastexam >= '2013-01-01' AND patient_info.lastexam <= '2013-12-31' OR patient_info.lastexam >= '2012-01-01' AND patient_info.lastexam <= '2012-12-31') 

GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

with the results in 5 columns: month, thisyear, totalthisyear, lastyear, totallastyear

but can't seem to figure out exactly how this could be done. The order of the columns is not important.
It could be: month, thisyear, lastyear, totalthisyear, totallastyear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0789c/3)

```
select
    to_char(('2012-' || m || '-01')::date, 'Month'),
    thisyear, lastyear, totalthisyear, totallastyear
from (
    select
        extract(month from m) as m,
        sum(case
            when firstexam between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31' then firstexam_count
            else 0 end
        ) as thisyear,
        sum(case
            when firstexam between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' then firstexam_count
            else 0 end
        ) as lastyear,
        sum(case
            when lastexam between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31' then lastexam_count
            else 0 end
        ) as totalthisyear,
        sum(case
            when lastexam between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' then lastexam_count
            else 0 end
        ) as totallastyear
    from
        generate_series (
            '2012-01-01'::date, '2013-12-31', '1 month'
        ) g(m)
        left join (
            select count(*) as firstexam_count, date_trunc('month', firstexam) as firstexam
            from patient_info
            where firstexam between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
            group by 2
        ) pif on firstexam = m
        left join (
            select count(*) as lastexam_count, date_trunc('month', lastexam) as lastexam
            from patient_info
            where lastexam between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
            group by 2
        ) pil on lastexam = m
    group by 1
) s
order by m
```

Comment: Not sure why, but the first column (thisyear) is the only column giving me a correct count. All the other columns actual numbers are lower than the code above is returning. For example, code above is returning for January 148, 230, 360, 238 but when I search individually, the actual numbers should be 148, 179, 275, 203. Any ideas where the error might be coming from?

Comment: @kipsoft What is the _when I search individually_ query?

Comment: SELECT firstexam from patient_info where firstexam between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31' (I am using the number of records returned for the count), then I just change the date range from 2013 to 2012 and the field from firstexam to lastexam to get the other results.

Comment: @kipsoft Ok check the new version.

Comment: I have a question I have been struggling with. Instead of calculating the lastexam from the patient_info table, I am trying to count the unique patient visits from the transactions table. Firstexam numbers are fine, but not all users update lastexam column with every transaction - so I need to modify this so that total patients for each month is the total number of patient visits for the month. This would normally be counted as total number of transactions, however, some patients might get two invoices in one day and that would only be counted as one patient visit).