# Monthly Total Count from Multiple Tables PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a search set up which gives total count of new patient visits and total count of patient visits, and comparing the totals for the requested year to the previous year's totals.

The SQL queries the date fields firstexam and lastexam from the table patient_info.

I have since found out that some users do not update the lastexam with every patient visit, and therefore the lastexam would not give the total number of patient visits.

Total number of patient visits can be obtained by searching the transactions table. Invoices in the transaction table are marked with the column transtype as 'Inv'. So, the total number of patient visits would be the total number of invoices in the date range (taking into account that two invoices entered for a patient in a single day count as one visit).

Below is the code for the SQL query set up based on firstexam and lastexam.

I have been struggling with this for some time now and am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select
        to_char(('2012-' || m || '-01')::date, 'Month'),
        thisyear, lastyear, totalthisyear, totallastyear
    from (
        select
            extract(month from m) as m,
            sum(case
                when firstexam between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31' then firstexam_count
                else 0 end
            ) as thisyear,
            sum(case
                when firstexam between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' then firstexam_count
                else 0 end
            ) as lastyear,
            sum(case
                when lastexam between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31' then lastexam_count
                else 0 end
            ) as totalthisyear,
            sum(case
                when lastexam between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' then lastexam_count
                else 0 end
            ) as totallastyear
        from
            generate_series (
                '2012-01-01'::date, '2013-12-31', '1 month'
            ) g(m)
            left join (
                select count(*) as firstexam_count, date_trunc('month', firstexam) as firstexam
                from patient_info
                where firstexam between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
                group by 2
            ) pif on firstexam = m
            left join (
                select count(*) as lastexam_count, date_trunc('month', lastexam) as lastexam
                from patient_info
                where lastexam between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
                group by 2
            ) pil on lastexam = m
        group by 1
    ) s
    order by m
```

Comment: So, is this query working or not? And if not, what seems to be the problem? As *always*, your version of Postgres? And you should at least provide a test case for us to work with, since you want us to do your work without asking a specific question. Consider http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15

Comment: Postgres 9.1.12 - This query does work. I am just trying to change the totalthisyear and totallastyear based on a query of the transactions table instead of the patient_info table. Trying to incorporate the result of something like: SELECT DISTINCT transactions.pt_number FROM transactions WHERE transactions.dateofservice between 2013-01-01 and 2013-12-31 and transactions.transtype = 'Inv'

Comment: Not looking for someone to do my work for me, I am just looking for some direction.

Comment: @kipsoft [I wrote the above query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25140310/131874) in a previous question of yours and even I can't understand it at first sight. The tables schema would be very helpful. `\d table_name`

Comment: Hope this helps. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93ebd/1)

Comment: *"...some users do not update the lastexam with every patient visit, and therefore the lastexam would not give the total number of patient visits."* You *probably* shouldn't be storing "firstexam" and "lastexam" anyway, since that data can be derived from the table "transactions". In your data, the transactions for patient 3 don't seem to mesh with the "firstexam" and "lastexam" dates: there's an invoice for neither the first exam nor the last exam. I suggest first you rewrite your query without referring "patient_info" at all.

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that. The first invoice date should always match patient_info.firstexam. The last invoice date does not have to match patient_info.lastexam. In some professions, lastexam date would happen only once or twice a year (such as an eye exam) even though there could be many invoices (patient visits) that year - total patients would be easily derived from the transaction table (SELECT DISTINCT). What would be a good way to total the number of patients' first exams using the transactions table?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to *report* information about exams, you ought to *store* information about exams.
2. More specifically, if you want to *count* exams, you ought to store information about *each* exam.
3. Don't use column names like "thisyear" and "lastyear". This year isn't 2013, although that's how you present it.
4. Usually, *visits* and *exams* are different things. Be careful with terminology. (Here it's not such a big deal, because we don't have information about either visits *or* exams. Only about invoices. Still, it's a good habit.)
5. If you're concerned about a particular output format, ask yourself whether you're building a query or a report. Build queries in SQL. Build reports with a report writer or application code.

For simplicity, I'm going to

- ignore the "patient_info" table,
- ignore the outer join you need in order to generate zeroes for months in which there were no exams, and
- use common table expressions. (In production I'd rather use views than common table expressions).

Let's start with just a table of transactions.

```
create table transactions (
  ptnumber INT,
  dateofservice date,
  transtype varchar(3)
);

-- Not quite the same data you started with.
insert into transactions (ptnumber, dateofservice, transtype) 
values
(1, '2012-01-01', 'Inv'),
(1, '2012-02-11', 'Inv'),
(2, '2012-01-02', 'Inv'),
(3, '2013-01-01', 'Inv'),
(4, '2013-02-12', 'Inv'),
(5, '2012-12-31', 'Inv'),
(5, '2013-12-31', 'Inv'),
(5, '2013-12-31', 'Inv'),
(6, '2013-06-21', 'Inv');
```

You said "two invoices entered for a patient in a single day count as one [exam]". I guess that means two or more.  So we can extract the set of patient exams like this. I expect two rows for patient 5--one in 2012 and one in 2013.

```
select distinct ptnumber, dateofservice
from transactions
where transtype = 'Inv' 
  and dateofservice between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
order by ptnumber;
```

```
ptnumber  dateofservice
--
1         2012-01-01
1         2012-02-11
2         2012-01-02
3         2013-01-01
4         2013-02-12
5         2012-12-31
5         2013-12-31
6         2013-06-21
```

This is the key to your whole problem--a set of distinct patient exams over a defined range of dates. Based on this set, counting patient visits by month is straightforward. (Counting them every which way is straightforward.)

```
with patient_exams as (
  select distinct ptnumber, dateofservice
  from transactions
  where transtype = 'Inv' 
    and dateofservice between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
)
select to_char(dateofservice, 'YYYY-MM') as month_of_service, count(*) as num_patient_exams
from patient_exams
group by 1
order by 1;
```

```
month_of_service    num_patient_visits
--
2012-01             2
2012-02             1
2012-12             1
2013-01             1
2013-02             1
2013-06             1
2013-12             1
```

**First exams**

Again, start by deriving a set that will give you reliable counts. You want one row per patient, and you want the earliest invoice date. The date of a patient's first exam has nothing to do with the date range you want to report; including the date range in this query's WHERE clause will give you the wrong data.

```
select ptnumber, min(dateofservice) as first_exam_date
from transactions
where transtype = 'Inv'
group by ptnumber
order by ptnumber;
```

```
ptnumber  first_exam_date
--
1         2012-01-01
2         2012-01-02
3         2013-01-01
4         2013-02-12
5         2012-12-31
6         2013-06-21
```

Now counting how many new patients you gained each month is straightforward.

```
with first_exams as (
  select ptnumber, min(dateofservice) as first_exam_date
  from transactions
  where transtype = 'Inv'
  group by ptnumber
)
select to_char(first_exam_date, 'YYYY-MM') exam_month, count(*) num_first_exams
from first_exams
where first_exam_date between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
group by 1
order by 1;
```

```
exam_month  num_first_exams
--
2012-01     2
2012-12     1
2013-01     1
2013-02     1
2013-06     1
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help. I ended up doing a combination of  Clodoaldo's suggestion and Mike's - searching for firstexam using the patient_info table and total visits using the transaction table.